# Cannot run NPM install because it's 'unable to resolve dependency tree'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, command-line-interface

I had some issues with my node_modules so I went to delete the node_modules and run `npm install`. Boy was that a mistake. My project is completely messed up. When I run `npm install` npm it sends back this:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"15.3.0 - 16.x" from react-vis@1.11.7
npm ERR! node_modules/react-vis
npm ERR!   react-vis@"^1.11.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/Cole/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Cole/.npm/_logs/2021-05-26T10_34_07_786Z-debug.log
```

Someone please help me!

Edit: Here is my package.json.

```json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "npm": "^7.14.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Not quite sure what I did that was so detrimental but this has been a painful experience.

When running `npm audit` it shows that there are 87 vulnerabilities.
Running `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` do not fix anything.

Is there a way to refresh all the node_modules? Go back to square one and re-install all dependencies again?

Comment: Can you share your package.json

Comment: Looks like the dependency react-vis is broken or corrupted, or is not compatible with the latest version of React anymore. Have you tried adding the  --force flag as suggested in the error trace?

Comment: Just added my package.json file. And I was just running react-vis with react a couple hours ago before it all stopped working. I hope that's not the problem

Comment: Try removing lock files package-lock or yarn.lock and run npm i again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `react-vis` has a peer dependency of `react@"15.3.0 - 16.x"`. Since you have react@17.0.2, it complains. Try changing

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
```

to

```
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
```